Parallel connections

When conecting components in parallel in a circuit, wich is the criterion to know if two circuits are equivalent?
For example, the figure shows two possible parallel connections of the lamp: is it the same in each of these circuits? Is connecting directly in parallel to the heater different from drawing a whole new branch?

This seems like a conceptual question to me.

@PM2Ring Because the answerer suggested an edit to it on which I voted to approve and submit for reopening.

The only difference between both circuits is that the switch of the heater also affect the lamp, but when all switch are closed the circuits are equal.
You can move cable nodes freely along a cable,  without jumping over any circuit component, and the circuits remain the same. This is because connect two points with a cable is the same of put them at the same potential. So all the left cable of your circuit is at one potential, and all the right part at other.

Thanks a lot! Yes, drawing my attention to the fact that the switch will affect it is helpful!

This is almost certainly a homework type question and should be dealt with appropriately.
